# MYSQL - CONCATENATE a lookup tables columns into one row

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following table structure:

[image: data structure]

tbl_catalogue_state
[image]

In tbl_catalogue there is a part number 58674 that has three states in the tbl_catalogue_state_lk table. Here is the result when I run a query inner joining the three tables.

[image]

As expected there are multiple rows returned.

Is there a way to only return one row having the values for each catalgue_state_id on the same row?

I would also like the ability to ignore a row for example:

```
select tbl_catalogue.catalogue_part, tbl_catalogue_state.catalogue_state_id from tbl_catalogue
inner join tbl_catalogue_state_lk on tbl_catalogue.catalogue_id = tbl_catalogue_state_lk.catalogue_id
inner join tbl_catalogue_state on tbl_catalogue_state_lk.catalogue_state_id = tbl_catalogue_state.catalogue_state_id
where tbl_catalogue_state_lk.catalogue_state_id <> 1;
```

The above select still returns two rows.

### UPDATE

I was able to use GROUP_CONCAT:

```
select tbl_catalogue.catalogue_part, GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_catalogue_state.catalogue_state_id) as cat_state from tbl_catalogue
inner join tbl_catalogue_state_lk on tbl_catalogue.catalogue_id = tbl_catalogue_state_lk.catalogue_id
inner join tbl_catalogue_state on tbl_catalogue_state_lk.catalogue_state_id = tbl_catalogue_state.catalogue_state_id
where tbl_catalogue_state_lk.catalogue_state_id <> 1
group by tbl_catalogue.catalogue_id;
```

My issue is the above statement still returns a row. I need it to return nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use not exists:

```
select tc.catalogue_part, GROUP_CONCAT(tcs.catalogue_state_id) as cat_state from tbl_catalogue as tc
inner join tbl_catalogue_state_lk as tcsl on tc.catalogue_id = tcsl.catalogue_id
inner join tbl_catalogue_state as tcs on tcsl.catalogue_state_id = tcs.catalogue_state_id
where 

not exists
(
    select tcsl2.catalogue_state_id from tbl_catalogue_state_lk as tcsl2
    where tcsl2.catalogue_state_id = 6 and tcsl2.catalogue_id = tc.catalogue_id
)
and 
not exists
(
    select tcsl3.catalogue_state_id from tbl_catalogue_state_lk as tcsl3
    where tcsl3.catalogue_state_id = 1 and tcsl3.catalogue_id = tc.catalogue_id
)

and 
not exists
(
    select tcsl3.catalogue_state_id from tbl_catalogue_state_lk as tcsl3
    where tcsl3.catalogue_state_id = 2 and tcsl3.catalogue_id = tc.catalogue_id
)
group by tc.catalogue_id;
```